# Firestore/Nuxt - How do I keep my mutation push from nesting the next set of results?

Tags: arrays, google-cloud-firestore, vuex, nuxt.js

I am trying to build my app so it does not read all 200+ documents on load but a handful at load and grab the rest as they scroll down.

I have working code that allows me to grab a page of results, say 2, then hit next and grab the next 2 but I want the next 2 to be added to the last so the user can scroll back up.

I am trying to push in my mutation but it's creating a nested mess. It returns 3 with the last having 2.

Mutations

```
setAddons(state, payload) {
        state.addons = payload;
      },
      nextAddons(state, payload) {
        state.addons.push(payload);
      },
```

My 2 actions. One loads up with the page to grab first set. The second right now when I hit a button, but hopefully linked to scroll event once I get this sorted.

```
async firstAddons({ commit }) {
        let addonsData = [];

        return await db
          .collection('addons')
          .where('publish', '==', true)
          .orderBy('timeUpdated', 'desc')
          .limit(10)
          .get()
          .then(querySnapshot => {
            querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
              addonsData.push({
                ...doc.data(),
                id: doc.id,
                timeUpdated: doc.data().timeUpdated.toDate(),
                timeCreated: doc.data().timeCreated.toDate()
              });
              let last = querySnapshot.docs[querySnapshot.docs.length - 1];
              commit('setLast', last);
            });
            commit('setAddons', addonsData);
          });
      },

      async nextAddons({ commit, state }) {
        let addonsData = [];

        await db
          .collection('addons')
          .where('publish', '==', true)
          .orderBy('timeUpdated', 'desc')
          .startAfter(state.last.data().timeUpdated)
          .limit(10)
          .get()
          .then(querySnapshot => {
            querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
              addonsData.push({
                ...doc.data(),
                id: doc.id,
                timeUpdated: doc.data().timeUpdated.toDate(),
                timeCreated: doc.data().timeCreated.toDate()
              });
              let next = querySnapshot.docs[querySnapshot.docs.length - 1];
              commit('setLast', next);
            });
            commit('nextAddons', addonsData);
            console.log(state.addons);
          });
      },
```

What is coming back

```
(3) [{…}, {…}, Array(2), __ob__: Observer]
0: {…}
1: {…}
2: Array(2)
  0: {…}
  1: {…}
  length: 2
length: 3
```

Expected results are that the next page of results should be pushed onto the end of the last results and carry on.

Actual results: The array is putting each set into a nested array.

How can I put these together in one continuous array to use in my template?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Solved and feel like a dope.

Turns out it was as simple as using spread.

```
setAddons(state, payload) {
        state.addons = payload;
      },
      nextAddons(state, payload) {
        state.addons.push(...payload);
      },
```

That is working!